# Hide a certain Table Row - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

## I have

a Table that contains 5 places.

```
var places =  ["lat": "42.61964890000001", "country": "United States", "name": "39 Cosgrove St", "lon": "-71.3031683"]
[["lat": "42.6285025", "country": "United States", "name": "138 B St", "lon": "-71.3288776"], ["lat": "42.6334255", "country": "United States", "name": "137 Pine St", "lon": "-71.3321021"], ["lat": "42.6225646", "country": "United States", "name": "98 Marriner St", "lon": "-71.31320219999999"], ["lat": "42.6252232", "country": "United States", "name": "48 Houghton St", "lon": "-71.3243308"], ["lat": "42.61964890000001", "country": "United States", "name": "39 Cosgrove St", "lon": "-71.3031683"]]
```

[image]

## I want

to prevent showing the active place from the list in my table.

## I try

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    
    if places[indexPath.row]["name"] != nil && places[indexPath.row]["name"] != places[activePlace]["name"] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

## I got

the text to hide, but it seems to leave an empty space which look really bad.

[image]

## I hope

someone can shed some lights on this.

Comment: you need to implement `prepareForReuse()` : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse and then reload tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is wrong. You need to remove the entry from your data model.

Say you have an array `places` that contains all your places.

You could change your table view to use a variable `tablePlaces` as it's data model

```
var tablePlaces: [[String, String]]
```

Then, to populate tablePlaces with your places, but remove the active place:

```
tablePlaces = places
tablePlaces.remove(at: activeIndex)
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Should I place your code in viewDidLoad() ? or in `cellForRowAt` ?

Comment: place it where **activeIndex** is changed , the problem with this approach is that it keeps a duplicated arrays you may save the removed object only and add it again the next time **activeIndex** is changed

Comment: "...the problem with this approach is that it keeps a duplicated arrays". That doesn't seem like a problem. You'd need THOUSANDS of large objects in the array for the amount of memory used to be meaningful, and even then those data objects would have to be quite large to cause significant memory pressure. If you made the data objects in the array reference type objects then they wouldn't be duplicated and the only extra memory would be the overhead for the pointers the array uses, which is trivial.

Comment: @DuncanC current case has a value type array of dics

Answer (score 2):

This

```
if places[indexPath.row]["name"] != nil && places[indexPath.row]["name"] != places[activePlace]["name"] {
    cell.textLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]
}
```

causes the return of an empty cell ( if not a dequeued one  ) , you need ro remove that info from the data source array ( may to retain it in another var or array if there are many of active ones ) and reload the table , you can use this

```
places = places.compactMap{ $0["name"] }
```

to remove the nils from the begining

---

Declare 2 temporary vars like

```
var tem:[String:String]? // pls create a model don't use array of dics
var activeIndex:Int?
```

suppose you change active in a method which gives the new active index say it's **neActiveIndex** then you would do

```
if let oldValue = tem && oldActi = activeIndex { // is it the first process 
  places.insert(oldValue,at:oldActi)  // return it to it's place
}

// remove the new index 

tem = places.remove(at: neActiveIndex) // remove also returns the deleted object 
activeIndex = neActiveIndex
```

then reload the table

**If the active index doesn't change and it's only a 1 time show  then don't retain anything just remove the active index inside `viewDidLoad` and the table itself will be reloaded upon vc initiation**

Comment: this is not a modification to your code it's an illustration of the problem and how to fix it

Comment: I will review and test this shortly. Thanks.